# Do you have to completely replace a property value to customise it?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'm having trouble figuring out how to customize components. Most of the examples showing how to customize replace the `background` of the component entirely. For example:

```
menuBar: MenuBar {
...
        background: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 40
            implicitHeight: 40
            color: "red"

            Rectangle {
                color: "#21be2b"
                width: parent.width
                height: 1
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            }
        }
}
```

Why can't I just do something like the following, since when I look in the source for `MenuBar.qml` it is already using a `Rectangle` for the `background`. I'd rather modify the exiting `background` rather than completely recreating it from scratch.

```
menuBar: MenuBar {
...
   background.color: "red";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your sole goal is to avoid replacing the background, you can go with this solution:

```
MenuBar {
    id: menuBar1

    Binding {
        target: menuBar1
        property: "color"
        value: "red"
    }
}
```

But I guess you will not like it, since it can get very verbose quickly.
You are probably better of writing your own implementation of MenuBar:

```
//MyMenuBar.qml

MenuBar {

    property alias backgroundColor: theBackground.color

    background: Rectangle {
        id: theBackground
   }
}
```

This component will inherit all the properties from the standard `MenuBar`, plus the added `backgroundColor` property.

---

Btw, there is the notion of [grouped properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#grouped-properties) but that doesn't work in this case, because `background` is declared as `QQuickItem`

Answer (score 0):

One other option is something that I have yet to find much documentation for. You can look at the source for `MenuBar` (or whatever other quick control you're interested in), and see what `palette` property it uses for the background. So this is what I see in the source code:

```
    background: Rectangle {
        implicitHeight: 40
        color: control.palette.button
    }
```

So if you just try setting `palette.button` to something else, it should change the color:

```
MenuBar {
    palette.button: "red"
}
```

That will only help with colors. If you want to change any other properties, you're better off just recreating the whole thing.